# Simplifying a series with multiset coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, multisets

I am struggling to simplify this series:
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \left(\!\!{n\choose k}\!\!\right) a^k k^2 =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} {n + k - 1\choose k}\ a^k k^2.$$

I understand that the square under the sum makes it harder, but I was wondering if there exists a simplification nevertheless.

Please, also write if you know any tricks that may help to reduce the power of $k$ under the summation, as without $k^2$ the series evaluates to $(1 - a)^{-n}$.

Comment: @user295357 This is *multichoose* and not *choose* (the usual binomial coefficient).

Comment: @ RobPratt  Oh, yes, you are right. Thanks.

Comment: The answer seems to be
$$\frac{an(an + 1)}{(1 - a)^{n + 2}},$$
for $a \in [0, 1)$. Although, I am still trying to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because
$$k\left(\!\!\binom{n}{k}\!\!\right) = n\left(\!\!\binom{n+1}{k-1}\!\!\right),$$
we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\!\!\binom{n}{k}\!\!\right) a^k k^2 
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\!\!\binom{n}{k}\!\!\right) a^k k^2 \\
&= n \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\!\!\binom{n+1}{k-1}\!\!\right) a^k k \\
&= n \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\!\!\binom{n+1}{k-1}\!\!\right) a^k (k-1+1) \\
&= n \sum_{k=2}^\infty \left(\!\!\binom{n+1}{k-1}\!\!\right) a^k (k-1)
 + n \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\!\!\binom{n+1}{k-1}\!\!\right) a^k \\
&= n(n+1) \sum_{k=2}^\infty \left(\!\!\binom{n+2}{k-2}\!\!\right) a^k
 + n \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\!\!\binom{n+1}{k-1}\!\!\right) a^k \\
&= a^2n(n+1) \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\!\!\binom{n+2}{k}\!\!\right) a^k
 + an \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\!\!\binom{n+1}{k}\!\!\right) a^k \\
&= a^2n(n+1) \frac{1}{(1-a)^{n+2}} + an \frac{1}{(1-a)^{n+1}} \\
&= \frac{an(an+1)}{(1-a)^{n+2}}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for the proof, the identity you used is very useful!

Comment: Yes, and the corresponding binomial coefficient identity $k\binom{n}{k}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ is often useful, too.